# Why does the Flask bool query parameter always evaluate to true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have an odd behavior for one of my endpoints in my Flask application which accepts boolean query parameters. No matter what I pass to it, such as `asfsdfd` or `true` or `false`, it is considered true. Only by leaving it empty does it become false.

```
full_info = request.args.get("fullInfo", default=False, type=bool)
if full_info:
    # do stuff
```

It seems to be that either any input is considered to be true. Is there any way to make this work with the Flask intended way of defining the type, or do I need to accept a string and compare it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `type` parameter of [`request.args.get`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) is not for specifying the value's type, but for specifying a **callable**:

> - **type** – A callable that is used to cast the value in the **MultiDict**. If a **ValueError** is raised by this callable the default value is returned.

It accepts a callable (ex. a function), applies that callable to the query parameter value, and returns the result. So the code

```
request.args.get("fullInfo", default=False, type=bool)
```

calls `bool(value)` where `value` is the query parameter value. In Flask, the query parameter values are always stored as strings. And **calling `bool()` on a non-empty string will always be `True`**:

```
In [10]: bool('true')
Out[10]: True

In [11]: bool('false')
Out[11]: True

In [12]: bool('any non-empty will be true')
Out[12]: True

In [13]: bool('')
Out[13]: False
```

Instead of `bool`, you can pass a function that explicitly checks if the string is equal to the literal string `true` (or whichever value your API rules consider as true-ish):

```
def is_it_true(value):
  return value.lower() == 'true'

@app.route("/test")
def test():
  full_info = request.args.get('fullInfo', default=False, type=is_it_true)
  return jsonify({'full_info': full_info})
```

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/test?fullInfo=false
{"full_info":false}

$ curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/test?fullInfo=adasdasd
{"full_info":false}

$ curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/test?fullInfo=11431423
{"full_info":false}

$ curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/test?fullInfo=
{"full_info":false}

$ curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/test?fullInfo=true
{"full_info":true}

$ curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/test?fullInfo=TRUE
{"full_info":true}

$ curl -XGET http://localhost:5000/test
{"full_info":false}
```

Answer (score 7):

A "trick" is to use `json.loads` as `type`. It will act as a "factory" that will build a bool `True`/`False` from the strings `'true'`/`'false'`

Comment: This doesn't work if somehow the passed parameter is `'True'/'False'` (though that in itself could be a bug on the frontend using capitalized T/F).

Comment: well, If you need to deal with more corner cases that the basic "true" -> True, "false" -> False, then you just need to write a function with the custom logic to translate the query parameter as string ("true", "false", "True", "yes", "no", "0", "1", "one", etc...) to the boolean values True / False.

Answer (score 1):

It would work properly if you use flask_restplus.inputs.boolean type instead of bool.
It's explained here. https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/199#issuecomment-276645303