# How to get a proper bool as result of my checkbox?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

have a standard checkbox in HTML and when i try to access the current value in Python
then i dont get proper True or False..

```
#Get the filter_active parameter from the URL
filter_active = request.args.get('filter_active')
```

i tried also request.args.get('filter_active', type= bool)
but in the debugger i see only 'false' or 'true'
and the request.args is always returning True , for all states..

here my html

```
 <div class="filter-active">
     <label for="filter-active">Show Active only:</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="filter-active" {% if filter_active != 'false' %}checked{%    endif %} onchange="filterAddressesByStartingLetter('ALL')">
 </div>
```

and my js.

```
``
function filterAddressesByStartingLetter(startingLetter) {
// Toggle the state of the filter_active checkbox
var filterActiveCheckbox = document.getElementById('filter-active');
console.log("Filter Active Checkbox:", filterActiveCheckbox.value);
//filterActiveCheckbox.checked = !filterActiveCheckbox.checked;

// // Get the current state of the filter_active checkbox
var filterActive = filterActiveCheckbox.value;
console.log("Filter Active:", filterActive);

fetch(`/addresses/${startingLetter}?filter_active=${filterActive}`)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
};
``
```

[Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVfqw.png)

What do i do wrong ?

Comment: inputs of type checkbox have an attribute [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#checked) which stores the boolean.

Comment: yes i thought so, but the debugger makes out of a 'false' a 'True'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575796/why-does-the-flask-bool-query-parameter-always-evaluate-to-true: `bool("false") is True`